# Two solutions for the same integral question, which approach is correct/better to solve?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I solved the following integral by 'u' substitution:

$\int \frac{y}{y+1}dy$

$ u = y + 1$

$ y = u - 1$

$=\int \frac{\left(u-1\right)}{u}du$

After finally separating nominator and denominator, and putting values of u, we get:

$=y+1-\ln \left|y+1\right|$

But my instructor does it this way(she basically divided the denominator with nominator):

$\int \left(1\:-\:\frac{1}{y+1}\right)dy$

which yields the following answer:

$=y-\ln \left|y+1\right|$

Which is slightly different from the answer yielded by 'u' substitution.

I wanted to know which method or approach is correct or better to solves such types of integral question?

Comment: These two primitives differ by a constant, hence they are both correct.

Comment: Both are wrong, they are missing the "constant of integration."

Comment: I won't be pedantic and point out the absence of an additive constant, because I think your question is more about which approach is better. You are now leaving behind the drilling sessions of school mathematics, (where questions have one correct answer, and must be solved quickly) and moving into the realms of true mathematics, where there are multiple approaches. My advice is to not confine yourself to thinking any one is better and find things to appreciate in both. Add them both to your problem solving kit.

Comment: Integration is a wonderful place where you first see how there are multiple approaches to problems.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive functions are determined only up to an additive constant. Both answers are equally correct...yet both are missing the addition of a constant.